# Moving the file structure for CSS in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a `index.html` file which has this file structure: `fl/contact/thanks/index.html`

My CSS folder has this file structure: `fl/css/style.css`

How can i target the `style.css` file so it affects the `index.html` file with the current file structure?

This is what it's currently set to:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">`

Comment: `../../css/style.css`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on a server, you could do this:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">`

This assumes that 'fl' is the root.

Comment: I agree if your using this in sub folders you should make the path absolute that way you can use this code anywhere and it will always resolve.

Answer (score 1):

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/style.css">`

each ".." for the upper layer of the path.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/style.css">
```

Comment: you only need 2 `../` as there are two folders to move up through, `/contact/thanks/`

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../css/style.css" />
```

That should be your new path for index.html.

Comment: check the number of folders you are moving through, you only need to move up twice not three times.

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to do it like this:

Updated answer

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/style.css" />
```

Comment: you only need 2 `../` as there are two folders to move up through, `/contact/thanks/`